# How to replace a substring with slashes

Tags: sh

How can I remove a substring with slashes?

```
#!/bin/sh
dir="/a/directory/last/which/last part/needs to/be/removed/end"
dir2=${dir/"last part/needs to/be/removed"}
echo $dir2
```

In this example the output should become

```
/a/directory/which/end
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `bash` syntax in `sh`.

Your options are:

- Change your shebang line to `#!/bin/bash` and change `dir2=${dir/"last part/needs to/be/removed/"}`
- Keep the shebang line as `#!/bin/sh` and change `dir2="$(echo ${dir} | sed -e 's/last part\/needs to\/be\/removed\///')"` where you will need to escape your `/`s

Answer (score 0):

One way    :

```
 dir2=${dir%last*}
```